# A question on limsup

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $a_n>0$. Prove that $$\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)\geq 1.$$

I argue by contradiction. If it is not ture, then $$\exists\ N,\ \forall\ n\geq N, n\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)<1\Rightarrow 1+a_{n+1}-a_n<\frac{a_n}{n}.$$
What contradiction shall I get then....

Comment: i think there are some typo mistakes, or i can't figure out what are $a_n$ and why the 2 limits are written differently ( first is divided by $n$, second $a_n$

Comment: @RicPed Let $a_n>0$ just means that the sequence we consider is positive.

Comment: yeah right, didn't pay attention :(

Comment: But, is it $n$ in the nominator or $a_n$????

Comment: @Berci Probably $a_n$, otherwise the statement is not correct (e.g. $a_n := \frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that for $n\ge N$,
$$
n\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)\lt1
$$
Then, for $n\ge N$,
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}\lt\frac{a_n}{n}-\frac1{n+1}
$$
It can be shown by induction that
$$
\frac{a_{n+k}}{n+k}\lt\frac{a_n}n-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac1{n+j}
$$
Since the harmonic series diverges, at some point $\dfrac{a_{n+k}}{n+k}<0$, contrary to the hypothesis that $a_n\gt0$.