# How to prove this limit superior?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that
$$ \limsup_{n \to +\infty} \;n\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right) \ge 1 $$
for any positive real sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your thoughts.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/395504/42969.

Comment: Thank you, Anonymous and Martin R! My textbook has given this question right after another one that asked reader to prove Raabe's test, and I have been trying to get a contradiction through Raabe. But it seems that just by the definition the question is quite easy.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!